# Windows 8 Data Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-8

I'm developing an application using C# and XAML and I've encountered a problem that is confusing me. I have a property in my data called `GroupImage` and have used binding to set the `Source` property of an `Image` with it. That worked fine but when I wanted to do the same thing a second time it doesn't show the image in the second `Image` control.

```
<Image Source="{Binding Group.GroupImage}" Width="250" Height="500" Stretch="UniformToFill" />

<Image VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="{Binding Group.GroupImage}" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
```

The top one works fine the bottom one doesn't. I have been reading about Data Binding and have gotten the impression that you need to specify something in the `DataContext` to use a property more than once. Is this right? It seems a very strange way of doing this.

I am relatively new to C# so sorry if I'm missing something obvious. I'd appreciate a more knowledgeable cluing me in.

Thanks

**Update** Following the assistance I received I figured out that the context was being set to

```
DataContext="{Binding Group}"
```

And as a result my second line needed to change to the following since the Data Context was already set to Group.

```
<Image VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="{Binding GroupImage}" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
```

Comment: There should be nothing wrong with binding multiple controls to the same `DataContext` property. Are you sure that both images have the same `DataContext`?

Comment: Could the `VerticalAlignment="Bottom"` be making the `Image` have an ActualHeight of 0? Have you tried giving the second `Image` specific dimensions?

Comment: When you say "it won't let me", what do you mean? A compiler error? An exception? Any binding errors? Post the errors you see.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific.  The image just doesn't show up.  No errors in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You don't need to specify something in the `DataContext` to use a property more than once.** But  your two `Image` have to have the right `DataContext` (you can easily test it with the debugger), depending on their location on the visual tree (You didn't provide any code for the `DataContext` part ?) .

You can also check that your `Image`'s `Width`/`Height` are not 0.

Comment: Yes when I checked in the debugger the data context had been set in a place I wasn't expecting.  Thanks for your help and patience with a newbie.